# If $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}=c\vec{x}+d\vec{y}$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried this by contradiction supposing $a\neq c$. Then, if $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}=c\vec{x}+d\vec{y}$, $\vec{x}=\dfrac{d-b}{a-c}\vec{y}$. That means $\vec{x}$ is parallel to $\vec{y}$ and substituting we get $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}=\dfrac{ad-bc}{a-c}\vec{y}$. And I'm stuck in this part.
I know I have to get a contradiction but I don't see how. Also I was thinking that it's pretty obvious that if $a\neq c$ then for whatever choice of scalars $b,d$ you get that $a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}\neq c\vec{x}+d\vec{y}$

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ linearly independent? Try moving everything to one side and use the definition of linearly independent vectors.

Comment: @spinosarus123 The problem is that this is from the book Multivariable Mathematics by Ted Shifrin and at this point he hasn't introduced dependence and independence of vectors. I'm stuck with the definition of parallel vectors at this point. So I don't think I'm aloud to use that in this problem.

Comment: If $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are linearly independent, from $(a-c) \vec x+(b-d) \vec y=\vec o$ follows (by definition $a-c=0$ and $b-d=0$. If they were linearly dependent, there one of them is a multiple of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advice from the author: Get in the habit of checking to see if you can reduce part b. of a problem to part a. This is how mathematics frequently works. In part a. you showed that if $sx+ty=0$ and $x$ and $y$ are non-parallel, then you must have $s=t=0$. Do not try to reinvent the wheel every time. What elementary algebra can you do to make this form appear? (You already did it to get to what you have.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the answer already and couldn't see it. My problem is exactly what you said, I try to reinvent the wheel every time. I tend to forget to use what I already proved 2 seconds ago. I will definitely follow your advice more carefully.

Comment: You're welcome, @QNVK. Remember that when you post questions here, you should make the questions self-contained, as many people here won't know my text and I may not see your question. You should make the hypotheses clear, as well as your efforts to solve the question :)